# How to determine properly data types when I have number in quotes or mixed data?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqldatatypes

I know that this is very simple questions but I can't go any further. I want to import data from csv file to PostgreSQL. I have made a table, name column as they are named on the file and first problem that I have got is that I don't know the data type. I mean in first column when i open CSV file i have something like that:

```
"COLUMN1";"COLUMN2";"COLUMN3";"COLUMN4"
"009910";NA;NA;"FALSE"
"953308";0;41;"TRUE"
"936540";NA;NA;"FALSE"
"902346";1;5;"TRUE"
"747665";NA;NA;"FALSE"
"074554";NA;NA;"FALSE"
"154572";NA;NA;"FALSE"
```

And when I am import this base via pgAdmin 4 its return error with datatype. I set column2 as Integer but it's kinda 'mixed'. The column 1 I also set as integer but numbers are in quote so I wonder if PostgreSQL see it as string. The same is up to column4. How should I properly determine data types of each column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During import it will cast the value to the column's type, if possible.
For example, if you do `SELECT 'FALSE'::boolean` it will cast and return `false`. `SELECT '074554'::int` works as well and returns `74554`.

But the bare characters `NA` will give you problems. If those are intended to be `null`, try to do a find/replace on the file and just take them out, so that the first row of data has `"009910";;;"FALSE"` and see if that works.

You could also have all columns as text, quote the `NA` values, and import.

Then create a new table, and use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` from the all-text table and manually cast or use `CASE` as needed to convert types.

For example, if you imported into a table called `raw_data`, and have a nicer table `imports`:

```
INSERT INTO imports
SELECT
  column1::int,
  CASE WHEN column2 = 'NA' THEN null ELSE column2::int END,
  CASE WHEN column3 = 'NA' THEN null ELSE column3::int END,
  column4::boolean
FROM
  raw_data
```